# How does GitHub's "Used by" section work?

Tags: github

I have [an open-source repo](https://github.com/AverageHelper/Gamgee) on GitHub called Gamgee. (It's a dinky little music queue bot built on Node.js, in case you're curious.) It's been around for not much more than a week and doesn't export anything useful as a package, yet GitHub already reports that this repo is "used by" another repository of the same name.

[image: GitHub's "Used by" section, showing a single package named "@DynAgilityLLC/gamgee"]

The referenced package is very small and doesn't seem to list any dependencies at its root package.json other than TypeScript. Is this a GitHub bug, or am I missing something here? If this is a GitHub bug, where might I report those?

Comment: If not publishing to npm, try setting `"private": true`

Comment: @AllanChain Done, but no change in the "Used by" indicator.